# R - setting equiprobability over a specific variable when sampling

Tags: r

I have a data set with more than 2 millions entries which I load into a data frame.

I'm trying to grab a subset of the data. I need around 10000 entries but I need the entries to be picked with equal probability on one variable.

This is what my data looks like with `str(data)`:

```
'data.frame':   2685628 obs. of  3 variables:
$ category   : num  3289 3289 3289 3289 3289 ...
$ id: num  8064180 8990447 747922 9725245 9833082 ...
$ text    : chr  "text1" "text2" "text3" "text4" ...
```

You've noticed that I have 3 variables : category,id and text.

I have tried the following :

```
> sample_data <- data[sample(nrow(data),10000,replace=FALSE),]
```

Of course this works, but the probability of sample if not equal. Here is the output of `count(sample_data$category)` :

```
      x freq
1  3289  707
2  3401  341
3  3482  160
4  3502  243
5  3601 1513
6  3783  716
7  4029  423
8  4166   21
9  4178  894
10 4785   31
11 5108  121
12 5245 2178
13 5637  387
14 5946 1484
15 5977  117
16 6139  664
```

**Update:** Here is the output of `count(data$category)` :

```
  x   freq
1  3289 198142
2  3401  97864
3  3482  38172
4  3502  59386
5  3601 391800
6  3783 201409
7  4029 111075
8  4166   6749
9  4178 239978
10 4785   6473
11 5108  32083
12 5245 590060
13 5637  98785
14 5946 401625
15 5977  28769
16 6139 183258
```

But when I try setting the probability I get the following error :

```
> catCount <- length(unique(data$category))
> probabilities <- rep(c(1/catCount),catCount)
> train_set <- data[sample(nrow(data),10000,prob=probabilities),]
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
incorrect number of probabilities
```

I understand that the sample function is randomly picking between the row number but I can't figure out how to associate that with the probability over the categories.

**Question :** How can I sample my data over an equal probability for the category variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the `stratified` function from my "splitstackshape" package perhaps?

Comment: That seems interesting. I don't know that packages. I'll give it a look. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get an equal number of cases for each unique x?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: But what happens if for example one of your categories has only, lets say, 5 entries within the whole data?

Comment: It will get the whole 5 of them then. I have added more details about the main data set.

Comment: Perhaps also interesting is from package dplyr sample_n and sample_frac combined with group_by.

Comment: The stratified function is the splitstackshape package seems to be similar to sample_n if i'm not mistaken. I can use to grab a sample portion of the data and it seems that if some groups contain fewer obs. all the obs in the group are returned from those groups.

Comment: I just took another look at dplyr::sample_n and in fact it requires you to return the same number of samples for each group. If any group has less observations than the desired sample size, you either have to sample with replacement or reduce the desired sample size.

Comment: `sample_n` and `sample_frac` behave similarly to `stratified(., category, size > 1)` and `stratified(., category, size < 1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could do this with some simple base R operation, though you should remember that you are using probabilities here within `sample`, thus getting the *exact* amount per each combination won't work using this method, though you can get close enough for large enough sample.

Here's an example data

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(category = sample(rep(letters[1:10], seq(1000, 10000, by = 1000)), 55000))
```

Then

```
probs <- 1/prop.table(table(data$category)) # Calculating relative probabilities
data$probs <- probs[match(data$category, names(probs))] # Matching them to the correct rows
set.seed(123)
train_set <- data[sample(nrow(data), 1000, prob = data$probs), ] # Sampling
table(train_set$category) # Checking frequencies
#  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j 
# 94 103  96 107 105  99 100  96 107  93
```

---

**Edit:** So here's a possible `data.table` equivalent

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, probs := .N, category][, probs := .N/probs]
train_set <- data[sample(.N, 1000, prob = probs)]
```

---

**Edit #2:** Here's a very nice solution using the `dplyr` package contributed by @Khashaa and @docendodiscimus

The nice thing about this solution is that it returns the *exact* sample size within each group

```
library(dplyr)
train_set <- data %>% 
             group_by(category) %>% 
             sample_n(1000)
```

---

**Edit #3:**
It seems that `data.table` equivalent to `dplyr::sample_n` would be

```
library(data.table)
train_set <- setDT(data)[data[, sample(.I, 1000), category]$V1]
```

Which will also return the *exact* sample size within each group

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was looking for `data.table` solution in your post and got disappointed :-)

Comment: @akrun, added. Though not sure its the optimal one

Comment: For the sake of completeness, can you add dplyr too?

Comment: Did you see  my last comment on the question (fyi) ? And would `setDT(data)[, sample(seq_len(.N), 10), category]` also work the same way?

Comment: @docendodiscimus `sample` will fail in each one of the above solutions if the `size` is bigger than `x` without `replace = TRUE`... And yes, in this case, `.I` is equivalent to `seq_len(.N)`

Comment: What? No `library(splitstackshape); stratified(data, "category", 1000)`? :-(

Comment: @Ananda, sorry I'm not familiar with this one. Is it similar to one of my data.table versions? You sure welcome either to edit or post your own answer ;)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, The code is not exactly similar to your approaches. Most of the code in the function is to create a table of sample sizes and subsetting rules. Then, using that table, it makes use of `by = .EACHI` to get the relevant rows. So, it's much more verbose than any of your answers, but lets you do something like `stratified(data, "category", .1, select = list(category = c("a", "b", "d")))`. It's now a somewhat redundant function now that there is `sample_n` and `sample_frac`, but I preferred it when the only other option were the functions from the "sampling" package.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I'm not sure that `sample_n` is not verbose underneath and only looks nice on top. If you created a nice `data.table` alternative to `sample_n` it is definitely can be useful. Either Way, I'd suggest you make an edit with some introduction to its capabilities, it could be beneficial for future readers IMO.